# How to check if character has been restricted in a TextInput?

Tags: apache-flex, textinput, flex-spark

Restricting characters in `TextInput` can be easily done, but how can I check if particular character was restricted without manually parsing the `restrict` property?

For example: `restrict='a-zA-Z^L-W'`.
How do i get that `B` is allowed and `M` is forbidden?

If it matters, I need this functionality to show a user the explanation why his key presses don't affect the input content.

I was able to implement the message by checking `input.text.indexOf(keydownchar)==-1`, but I'm interested if there's any SDK method to check the char without trying to append it into the input control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with

```
StringUtil.restrict(str:String, restrict:String):String
```

It is exactly the method used by text display controls like `RichEditableText` to handle `restrict` property.

There's also more suitable method for testing single char, but unfortunately it's private:

```
StringUtil.testCharacter(charCode:uint, restrict:String):Boolean
```

Anyways it is used inside `StringUtil.restrict`, so using `StringUtil.restrict` instead of `testCharacter` will produce the same result with performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no SDK method to check the incoming char.  You'll have to query the `restrict` text (ideally on the `changing` event).